# Operator '-' is not supported for operands of type 'string'. Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking to use my code to calculate to implement a KNN classifier however I am getting an error when trying to calculate my equation for the Euclidean distance.

I am getting the following error:

```
Operator '-' is not supported for operands of type 'string'.

Error in A2Q1 (line 18)
    equation = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2 + (a1-a2)^2 );
```

Please find the portion of my code with the error below and help me to fix it

```matlab
while counter <= 13

    counter = counter + 1;
    x1 = table2array(T([counter],[1]));
    y1 = table2array(T([counter],[2]));
    z1 = table2array(T([counter],[3]));
    a1 = table2array(T([counter],[4]));
    equation = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2 + (a1-a2)^2 );
    result{counter} = equation;

end
resultcolumn = result';
```

The equation line is the one causing the error.

Comment: Are the items in `x1` etc strings?

Comment: Maybe you need to convert: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html

Comment: The items in x1 etc. are single numbers. Where would I apply str2double?

Comment: @NavdeepSingh Obviously they're not. Please provide a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to trace your code back and examine the data types of the variables `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`, `z1`, `z2`, `a1`, `a2` and see if any of them became the 'string' data type somewhere in your program

Answer (score 2):

If indeed your arrays are arrays of strings (just guessing here) you can do something like this:

```
>> x1 = ["1.2" "3.14" "42"]

x1 = 

1×3 string array

"1.2"    "3.14"    "42"
```

To illustrate your error:

```
>> x1(1) - x1(2)
Operator '-' is not supported for operands of type 'string'.
```

To fix the problem:

```
>> for n=1:length(x1)
x2(n) = str2double(x1(n));
end
>> x2

x2 =

1.2000    3.1400   42.0000
```

Comment: This: `'1.2'` is not a string in MATLAB, it is a character array... This: `"1.2"` is a string. Strings can be part of a string array, whereas chars have to live within a cell array. I think your solution stands, but it's worth being clear on the data types since that's what this question is about

Comment: @Wolfie - Thank you for clearing that up. You are absolutely correct that the nomenclature should be accurate. I will adjust the answer. I guess then the OP is dealing with elements like "1.2" rather than '1.2'.

Comment: However, Matlab is not being fair to us by calling a function that converts a 'character array' `str2double`. It should be something like `char_array2double`.

Comment: The `str___` functions like `str2double` and `strcat` pre-date the introduction of the string variable type by many years, and have been retained for continuity. But yes, this topic can be a little confusing, especially when some built-in functions only accept strings or chars